# Tikz: clipping path from external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, path-clipping

I would like to use the data of an external file as the clipping path with Tikz. Something in the line of:

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{filecontents*}{spiral.dat}
6.5066069e-01  -7.0560046e-01
5.7783540e-01  -7.4892495e-01
5.0112891e-01  -7.8376476e-01
4.2139313e-01  -8.0997113e-01
3.3947853e-01  -8.2749913e-01
2.5623414e-01  -8.3640761e-01
1.7250756e-01  -8.3685920e-01
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip file {spiral.dat};
    \fill[red] (0,0) circle (5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, what is above does not work but is there an existing similar strategy? I could also directly define the clipping path in the Tike figure by importing the data from the external file but I want to avoid this.

Comment: The provided path is not closed but this is just an illustrative example. I was not aware of the `tikzfadingfrompicture` feature. How could it be adapted here?

Comment: Actually doesn't seem to work with draw rather than fill so you'd still need a closed path (or let TiKZ close it, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot the file but you need floats not sci representations. Then you can use simply `\clip plot file {spiral.dat};`.

Otherwise you can read the table via `pgfplotstable` and carry out the coordinate creation that TikZ would understand, or simply use `pgfplots`

### Sane input table

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{filecontents*}{spiral.dat}
1.00000000  -0.10000000
0.98518595  -0.19563549
0.96101356  -0.28698521
0.92795372  -0.37325320
0.88655701  -0.45369864
0.83743510  -0.52767006
0.78126033  -0.59460623
0.71875144  -0.65404381
0.65066069  -0.70560046
0.57783540  -0.74892495
0.50112891  -0.78376476
0.42139313  -0.80997113
0.33947853  -0.82749913
0.25623414  -0.83640761
0.17250756  -0.83685920
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip plot[no marks] file {spiral.dat};
    \fill[red] (0,0) circle (5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```